# How to change background color for specific item in map array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How can I make each product card to change it's bubble background color, also each product cart to have one ? As you can see on picture only first card has bubble with color. The problem is that if I choose a color from the second card it change the color in the first card, also the second card doesn't have bubble inside.

[image]

Here is the map function:

```
{products.map(product => {
                                return(    
                                    <div className="product--Container" key={product._id}>
                                        <div className="product--TopButton--Container">
                                            <button className="about--Button" onClick={() => productData(product._id)}>About</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="color--Background" style={{backgroundColor: color[0] === product._id ? `${color[1]}` : ""}} />
                                        <img src={product.imageUrl} alt="product image" />
                                        <div className="product--Colors--Container">
                                            {product.color.map(color => {
                                                return(
                                                    <button name="color" value={color.value} style={{backgroundColor: `${color.value}`}} onClick={() => colorPicker([product._id, color.value])}/>
                                                )
                                            })}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="product--About--Container">
                                            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                                            <p>{product.price}$</p>
                                        </div>
```

Here is the state and the function:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState([]);

const colorPicker = ([productId, colors]) => {
        setColor([productId, colors])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split this code into a smaller component so it only affects its own state

```js
{products.map(product => (<SmallerComponent product={product} />)}
```

In the smaller component

```js
function SmallerComponent({product}) {
  const [color, setColor] = useState([]); //Have its own state

  const colorPicker = ([productId, colors]) => {
    setColor([productId, colors])
  }

  return (<>
  <div className="product--Container" key={ product._id }>
    < div className="product--TopButton--Container">
      < button className="about--Button" onClick={ ()=> productData(product._id) } > About
        < /button>
          < /div>
            < div className="color--Background" style={ { backgroundColor: color[0]===p roduct._id ? `${color[1]}` : "" } } />
            < img src={ product.imageUrl } alt="product image" />
            < div className="product--Colors--Container"> { product.color.map(color => { return (
              < button name="color" value={ color.value } style={ { backgroundColor: `${color.value}` } } onClick={ ()=> colorPicker([product._id, color.value]) } /> ) }) }
                </div>
                  <div className="product--About--Container">
                    <h3> {product.name} </h3>
                    <p> { product.price } $ </p>
  </div>
  </>); // wrap in fragments)
```

The second card doesn't have a bubble inside maybe because of this condition. They use the same class so I think they should get the same effect

```
 style={{backgroundColor: color[0] === product._id ? `${color[1]}` : ""}}
```

Another way is you can create a unique id for the element you want to change color then create a function change color by that id

```js
const changeBtnAndBGColor = (idBG,idBtn,color)=>{
  // change color by id
  document.getElementById(idBG).style.backgroundColor = color;
   document.getElementById(idBtn).style.backgroundColor = color;
}

//Make sure you set id element is unique
{
  products.map(product => {
        return (<div className="product--Container" key={product._id }>
  <div className="product--TopButton--Container">
    <button className="about--Button" onClick={ ()=> productData(product._id) }> About
      </button>
        </div>
          <div id={'background'+product._id} className="color--Background" />
      <img src={product.imageUrl} alt="product image" />
        <div className="product--Colors--Container">
          {product.color.map(color => {
          const idBtn= product._id+color.value;
          return(
          <button id={product._id+color.value} name="color" value={color.value} 
          onClick={()=>changeBtnAndBGColor('background'+product._id,idBtn,color.value)}/>
                                                        )
                                                    })}
```

Comment: Split the product card into a Component <ProductCard /> and pass `product` as it props then your ProductCard  component will have its own color state

Comment: Is there a way to make it in this product.map(... function. I need to change a lot of thinks in this solution. Can we use the product key or something ?

Comment: Split component into a smaller component is will make it looks cleaner and easy to maintain but if you don't want to change a lot in your code try this `{products.map(product => { const [color,setcolor] = useState('red');   return(  ` I haven't try to this before but you can declare a variable in a map loop so give it a try

Comment: I tried it but you can use useState only in function :(

Comment: You can create a function that updates an element by id then in every product card you set a different id

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232421/discussion-between-cadmus-and-yollo).